# Angular 2 prevent click on parent when clicked on child

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a click event nested one level. When i click on the child the expected function is called but the parent's function is also called. Here is the code

```
<li class="task-item" *ngFor="let task of tasks" (click)="showTask(task.name)">
    <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="task.taskStatus" (ngModelChange)="changeTaskStatus($event)" />
</li>
```

So when the checkbox changes `changeTaskStatus()` and the `showTask()` called together. I want the parent to keep quiet when checkbox changes. How do I achieve this? It was easy to handle this in Angular 1

Things I've tried that failed

Used `$event.stopPropagation()` in the checkbox's click event that changed nothing

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="task.taskStatus" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (ngModelChange)="changeTaskStatus($event)" />
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CsfL5oHPcxQJ2Zt7HOn2?p=preview

This is working .

Comment: The code in plnkr works but the same doesn't work for me! The `<li>` repeats and all checkboxes have same ngModel is that the problem?

Comment: I figured it out. I had a custom CSS on the checkbox that was causing the problem.

Comment: Please add your solutions in an answer box, rather than as edits to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need to use `stopPropagation()` for checkbox event:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="task.taskStatus" (ngModelChange)="changeTaskStatus($event);$event.stopPropagation()" />
```

It prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Also, you probably need to add `stopPropagation()` to `click` event of checkbox, but I'm not 100% sure:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="task.taskStatus" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (ngModelChange)="changeTaskStatus($event)" />
```

Comment: This one worked 
   `<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="task.taskStatus" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (ngModelChange)="changeTaskStatus($event)" />`

Comment: Thanks for the good hint @AshikBasheer! That worked for me too. I don't think that the initial answer is still correct, because in ngModelChange, $event is not an event, but just the changed value (in case of a checkbox its just a boolean!). Thus trying $event.stopPropagation() there failed in my case.

Answer (score 37):

Just you need to add  **$event.stopPropagation()** code on **Child div** on click event

```
 <input  (click)="onChildClickFunction();$event.stopPropagation()"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is known as **Event Bubbling**.
*Events are first handled by the innermost element and then propagate to the outer elements until they reach the root.*

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userList">
  <div (click)="setUserData(item)">
    <a (click)="getUserDetails(item.user.id)">Name - {{item.user.name}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, when you click on username or  tag, it will first call inner element i.e. getUserDetails() and the root element i.e. setUserData().

So, to prevent this event bubbling, just add

> event.preventDefault();

in defination of getUserDetails($event) or

```
<a (click)="getUserDetails(item.user.id); $event.stopPropagation();">Name - {{item.user.name}}</a>
```

That's all you need to you.