# MatCheckbox preventDefault() and event.checked value

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling, angular-material2

How can I achieve a Material checkbox so It won't get checked/unchecked by default (eg. calling `preventDefault()` on the event) and also get the `checked` value from the event?

It seems like I can only achieve one of the conditions. Using the `(click)` event I cannot get the checkbox's value and using the `(change)` event I can't prevent the default checkbox value change (I will only change the checkbox value if the underlying HTTP request was successful).

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/matcheckbox-checked

```
<mat-checkbox 
  [checked]="checked"   
  (click)="onClick($event)"
>onClick me!</mat-checkbox>

<br/>

<mat-checkbox 
  [checked]="checked"
  (change)="onChange($event); false"
>onChange me!</mat-checkbox>

export class CheckboxOverviewExample {
  checked: boolean = false;

  onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('onClick event.checked ' + event.checked);
    console.log('onClick event.target.checked '+event.target.checked);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    // can't event.preventDefault();
    console.log('onChange event.checked '+event.checked);
  }
}
```

The `(click)` event prints `undefined` values, but successfully prevents the event propagation, the `(change)` event prints the value but will propagate the event.

Connected issues:

- https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1142
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2042
- https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13156

Comment: you want to disable checkbox ?

Comment: @Chellappan No, I want to manually change the value of the checkbox (checked or not checked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the check box manually @ViewChild get the ref of the element then use checked to set the value true or false like this

```
@ViewChild('ref') ref;

  onClick(bool){
    this.ref._checked=bool;
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/matcheckbox-checked-ybru81

Same example while event handling: https://stackblitz.com/edit/matcheckbox-checked-a1le6o

Answer (score 4):

In my personal case, I have to code for mouse and also for keyboard events, in case you care about accessibility you know :)

if you hit 'Space' it with still check, so (click) is not enough, you also need to include (keydown). No just that but after I fixed the issue with the Space, I noticed that it will also block the Tab which I need it to navigate with the keyboard, so I just had to add a little code for that

```
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)" 
        [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
        (click)="toggleDescendants(node,$event)"
        (keydown)="toggleDescendants(node,$event)"
        >
        {{node.name}}
      </mat-checkbox>
```

In Code

```
  toggleDescendants(node, $event) {
    this._logger.debug('toggleDescendants()');
    this.treeControl.toggleDescendants(node);
    if ($event.code !== 'Tab') {
      $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent default action on "change" with a provider in the component:

```
providers: [{
    provide: MAT_CHECKBOX_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, 
    useValue: { clickAction: 'noop' } as MatCheckboxDefaultOptions
}]
```

(source: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#noop)

and you can bind the checked to a local variable (or a getter function)

```
<mat-checkbox
(click)="changeValue()"
[checked]="theValue"
>
   Whatever
</mat-checkbox>
```

So, in the code, for examle, you use theValue as the value, and set that value programmatically. This way you do not need to receive the checkbox state as a parameter of the click method, you can access it from theValue.

```
theValue: boolean = false;

changeValue(): void {
    this.theValue = !this.theValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try indeterminate

**check**
Toggle checked value of the checkbox, ignore indeterminate value. If the checkbox is in indeterminate state, the checkbox will display as an indeterminate checkbox regardless the checked value.

**check-indeterminate**
Default behavior of mat-checkbox. Always set indeterminate to false when user click on the mat-checkbox. This matches the behavior of native "input type="checkbox""

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#-code-check-code-

Answer (score -1):

We cannot control the default behavior of checkbox and event properties. You can create 2 image icons with checked and unchecked state, toggle it based on value.